# How to configure form in component for getting data from reactive form using for loop

Tags: angular, forms, formarray, angular-reactive-forms

I created a form in template, code is given below:

```
<form action="#" [formGroup]="masterDataEntryForm" (ngSubmit)="submitMasterDataEntry(e)"
            id="masterDataEntryForm" #e="ngForm">
                <div class="modal-body">
                <div class=" row form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 row" style="padding: 10px;" *ngFor="let fields of masterDataFieldList; let i = index">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>{{fields.name}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="saveNew" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor:pointer;" (click)="s_submitted = true;">Save & New</button>
                <button type="submit" name="saveClose" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor:pointer;" (click)="s_submitted = true;">Save & Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="closeMasterDataEntryModal()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

How can I configure the component for getting the data on submitting the form, Please help me

Answer (score 1):

In html

```
   <form action="#" [formGroup]="masterDataEntryForm" (ngSubmit)="submitMasterDataEntry(e)"
            id="masterDataEntryForm" #e="ngForm">
                <div class="modal-body">
                <div class=" row form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 row" style="padding: 10px;" *ngFor="let fields of masterDataFieldList; let i = index">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>{{fields.name}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName = "{{fields.name}}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="saveNew" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor:pointer;">Save & New</button>
                <button type="submit" name="saveClose" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor:pointer;">Save & Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="closeMasterDataEntryModal()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

in component

```
    masterDataEntryForm: FormGroup;


    ngOnInit() {
    this.masterDataEntryForm = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
}

    getMasterDataFieldList(masterDataId) {
        let filterObj = {
          'column': 'type_id',
          'filter': masterDataId,
          'type': 'equals',
          'filterCondition': 'OR'
      };
        this._masterDataService.getMasterDataFields(masterDataId, filterObj).then((data) => {
        if (data['getMasterDataFields']['data']) {
          this.masterDataFieldList = data['getMasterDataFields']['data'];
          this.populateMasterDataFieldList();
          this.masterDataEntryForm = this.createNewControl(this.masterDataFieldList);
        }
      });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `[(ngModel)]`:

In HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="inputText"/>
</div>
```

In TS-File:

```
...

@Component
export class YourClassName implements OnInit {

inputText = '';

...

submitMasterDataEntry() {
// You can now get the value of the string inputText

console.log(this.inputText);

// Or just do what you want with it.
}
```